# Cambiar option del select firefox

Tags: css, firefox

tengo un select y los options con un estilo en css hecho. En chrome se ve bien, ahora en firefox los options no salen con el mismo estilo, esta cogiendo el suyo propio. En diferentes versiones de  firefox se va viendo con diferente estilo. He intentado con -moz-apperance:none !important; que no se vea el estilo predeterminado que tiene pero nada. Tambien en forzarle el estilo y nada. 
la pregunta es como puedo cambiar el estilo al select y sus hijos en este caso los options,  en firefox? Se me esta haciendo imposible y creo que s epuede hacer de manera  sencilla.

```
<select class="login-mobile-link" href="https://www.link.es/login">
        <option value="#">Usuario</option>
        <option value="https://www.link.es/ajustes">Ajustes</option>
        <option value="https://www.link.es/ajustes/password">Contraseñas</option>
        <option value="https://www.link.es/descargas/">Descargas</option>
        <option value="https://www.link.es/wp-login.php?action=logout&amp;redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.link.es%2Flogin%2F&amp;_wpnonce=6fa277ff58">Cerrar sesión</option>
    </select>

.login-mobile-link {
   position: absolute;
   top: -30px;
   left: -30px;
   width: 254px;
   padding: 7px 21px;
   background-color: #444444;
   color: #fff;
   font-weight: 600;
   text-decoration: none;
   -moz-appearance: none !important;
}**

.login-mobile-link:before {
   font-weight: 600;
   padding-right: 5px;
}

a.login-mobile-link{
   color:white !important;
}
```

Asi se ve en chrome y correctamente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y asi incorrectamente en firefox y no encuentro la manera de cambiarlo y que se vea igual que en chrome

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías ponernos el **HTML** y el **CSS** que estás usando. Sin ver esto resulta imposible ver que es lo que te puede estar sucediendo.

Comment: @PHPMyguel listo!

Comment: ¿Qué es exactamente lo que no se te ve igual entre navegadores? Estoy haciendo pruebas y no consigo reproducirlo. Si subieses una imagen de lo que ves en cada navegador sería perfecto.

Comment: @PHPMyguel imagenes subidas!

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Firefox estás usando? En la versión 62.0.2, que es con la que estoy haciendo las pruebas, me visualiza correctamente los CSS. De todas formas prueba a asignarle estilos específicos a los option del select. Tú le estás asignando estilo al select y es posible que el problema esté en que los option no lo estén heredando. **EDIT:** Me he fijado en que le estás poniendo un href al option. Este atributo es propio de las etiquetas **a**, hasta donde yo sé no estaría haciendo nada en tu select.

Comment: @PHPMyguel Estoy usando la  63.0. He probado también en aplicarle el mismo estilo que tengo en el select al option pero nada.

Comment: Un href al select, quería decir en el **EDIT** de mi anterior comentario.

Comment: @PHPMyguel Me lo acabo de mirar lo del select, en caso de que el usuario no este logueado ahi aparece login y te lleva a la pagina de login sin problemas.

Comment: Es posible que el problema lo tengas en alguna configuración de tu navegador. Para descartarlo lo probaría en otro dispositivo, como por ejemplo en tu móvil y así compruebas si ahí también se reproduce.

Comment: Probado en firefox 63 y funciona, haz pruebas borrando la caché o utilizando una nueva ventana privada.

Comment: @YESIDDOTNET Lo veo igual de mal en privada, Lo ves con el fondo negro? etc...

Comment: Si señor, se ve con fondo gris oscuro y fuente blanca https://ibb.co/h37p2A